# How to Get Prediction when when NetTrain Option All is set?

Tags: neural-network, wolfram-mathematica

I created a simple Perceptron,and I trained it

```
trained = 
NetTrain[net, {{1, 1} -> 0, {1, 0} -> 1, {0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1} -> 1}, 
        All]
```

The problem is when the option All is set I 've no idea how to get a prediction.  I tried trained[{1,1}], trained[1,1], trained[{{1,1}}] and none worked.
By the way, if I don't use All than I can get my prediction, but now I cannot extract the weights and biases, or get the nice network graph.